# How do you simplify $\cos a\cdot(\cos(4a) + 2\sin^2 (2a))$?

Tags: trigonometry

Any help with this question will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it the $2\sin^2(2a)$ or $2\sin^2(2A)$?

Comment: And is it $\cos(A)\cdot (\ldots)$ or $\cos(A\cdot(\ldots))$ ?

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Also, you can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: @missiledragon: I edited your question the way I understood it. Feel free to re-edit.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am new here and really don't understand much of what to do, or how to do it :D. Loving the site though :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use $\cos 4a=1- 2\sin^2 2a$

According to the edited version of the question, your expression becomes

$$\cos (a)(1-2\sin^2(2a)+2\sin^2(2a))=\cos (a)$$

Comment: THANKYOU!!!! :D I got it :D, cosA.